# Why switch statement in not comparing the int values?

Tags: java, switch-statement, boolean

**I wrote a simple code that have to compare to numbers, but when I run it compiler say me that has a error with boolean values. I dont understand why it doesnt work **

````
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        compare(8,22);
    }

    static void compare(int a, int b){
        switch (a) {
            case (a > b) -> System.out.println(a + " > " + b);
            case (b < a) -> System.out.println(a + " < " + b);
            case (a == b) -> System.out.println(a + " = " + b);
            default -> System.out.println("Something is wrong !");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: You can't not use switch with this statement. Change it to `if else` statement.

Comment: Would be good idea to show why you come up with this syntax, link similar to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html would make question better.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
{
    public static void main( String... args ) 
    {
        compare( 8, 22 );
    }

    static void compare( final int a, final int b )
    {
        switch( Integer.signum( Integer.compare( a, b ) ) ) 
        {
            case 1 -> System.out.println( a + " > " + b );
            case -1 -> System.out.println( a + " < " + b );
            case 0 -> System.out.println( a + " = " + b );
            default -> System.out.println( "Something is wrong !" );
        }
    }
}
```

And it should work!

`case` requires distinct constant expressions, and the terms that you use (`(a > b)`, `(b < a)` and `(a == b)`) are no constants (not to mention that `(a > b)` and `(b < a)` are equivalent). They also return a boolean. `switch` does not handle a boolean switch selector directly.

In JShell, (only) this works for `switch` with "boolean":

```
boolean flag = …

switch( Boolean.toString( flag ) )
{
  case "true" -> …
  case "false" -> …
  default -> throw new Error( "Hä?" ); 
}
```